# Extract part of string and change it to bold and add it to TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

i have a string with a text with some sentences for example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore [et dolore magna aliquyam erat], sed diam voluptua. ?At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren

In this text i added two square brackets " [, ]" which should locate the part i want to show in bold.

Now it want to extract the part between these brackets with this regex:

```
(?<=\[).+?(?=\])
```

Make it bold with:

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("regex here");
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

and add it to one string and show it in a TextView.

I have got the functions to do this, but i don't know how to combine it.

Hope you guys can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i made a little example for you. It is exactly what you want.

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button_action);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.title);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore [et dolore magna aliquyam erat], sed diam voluptua. ?At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren";
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[[\\w ]+\\]");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
                while (matcher.find())
                    text = text.replace(matcher.group(), matcher.group().replace("[", "<b>").replace("]", "</b>"));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
                } else {
                    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```